# Is it good practice to have JSON objects with data that won't be saved to DB?

Tags: json, database, api, api-design

I'll explain my question with an example: Let's say I have a backend with a SQL DB and a REST API that servers JSON. There's a claims resource in the API which describes claims about an order which contains articles. When I list all the claims I'd like the JSON object for each order claims to have these fields, to limit the API calls:

```
{
  "customerNumber": "112235-12312",
  "customerName": "A name"
  "orderNumber": "6575-12316",
  "claims": [
    {
        "articleNumber": "24141241",
        "articleName": "Article Name",
        "claimed": 3
    },
        ...
  ],
}
```

For consistency reasons I want the JSON object to be the same for all the HTTP verbs, but in the creation or update of a resource I don't know if it's good practice to send data to the backend which will not be saved to the DB, in this case customerName or articleName. I'd really like to have this data in the JSON object when listing cliams, otherwise, I would have to make many API calls and would make everything slower.

Comment: There's no real harm in it, beyond a little wasted bandwidth.

Comment: Thanks for answering... What I'm wondering is if it's good practice or not, what do you think?